# Giving Higher Precedence to less.css

Tags: css, less

I am trying to load less file after all the css file gets loaded .
How to control the ordering of loading of css files and less files

for example I trying to load in these order

```
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="syle.css" />
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="mysytle.less" />
```

but less is getting loaded first and style getting loaded after less

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="mysytle.less" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="syle.css" />
```

Comment: What? LESS is never used directly. Do you mean you want the CSS that was created from the LESS file to be loaded after the handwritten CSS files?

Comment: yes , similar to that

Comment: You have to explicitly include css in order you desired, or if you using some kind of build system and it collecting all style files from some directory, you can give number profixes for your style files: 01_some-file.css, ... and so on